# Halfmanualy crop image

Tags: gimp, script-fu, resize-crop

I have a few hundred photos. Each photograph is one object. And with each photo repeat the same steps: 
Open, select the area; crop, resize, fix brightness, save.

My attempt to automate the process: write a script and hang it on a hotkey.

```
(define (script-fu-cut800 inText inFont inFontSize inTextColor) 

; get the coordinates of allocation 
(gimp-image-get-selection (image)) 

(let * (
(original-left (car (????))) 
(original-top (car (????))) 
(original-width (car (gimp-image-width image))) 
(original-height (car (gimp-image-height image))) 
(new-width (- original-width (+ right left))) 
(new-height (- original-height (+ top bottom))) 
) 

; crop the selected image 
(gimp-image-crop image new-width new-height left top) 

; resize to 800 * 800 
(gimp-image-resize image 800 800 0 0) 

; open dialogue correction levels 
(?????) 

; save as JPG 80% compression of the same name 
(file-jpeg-save ????) 

))
```